# $Tf = xf(x)$ is not compact in $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

I want to prove, in a rather elementary way, that $Tf = xf(x)$ is not compact in $L^2([0,1])$. I cannot find the appropriate bounded sequence whose image has no Cauchy sub-sequences. I have tried variants of $f_n(x) = \sqrt n\cdot I_{[0,1/n]}$ to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its spectrum is $[0,1]$, so it is not discrete, however this does not count as "elementary", right?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen that theorem yet, so I would like to keep it more basic. I've seen counterexamples for similar operators, but can't find anything quite on the mark.

Comment: Restrict your $T$ to $L^2([1/2,1])$. Notice that $f/2\leq Tf\leq f$ for nonnegative $f$ in that subspace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with an orthonormal set $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $L^2[1/2,1]$, and extend the functions to be $0$ on $[0,1/2]$ in order to obtain an orthonormal set $\{ \tilde{f}_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $L^2[0,1]$. Then, for $n\ne m$,
\begin{align}
    \|T\tilde{f}_n-T\tilde{f_m}\|^2 & =\|x\tilde{f}_{n}-x\tilde{f}_m\|^2 \\
    & =\int_{1/2}^{1}x^2|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2dx \\
    & \ge \frac{1}{4}\int_{1/2}^{1}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2dx \\
    & = \frac{1}{4}(\|f_n\|_{L^2[1/2,1]}^2+\|f_m\|^2_{L^2[1/2,1]})=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Similarly, expand $x = \sum a_n e_n$ where $e_n$ are the exponentials, so $x e_k = \sum a_n e_{n+k}$ so $||x e_k - x e_\ell|| \geq \sum |a_n - a_{n - k + \ell}|^2$ which can be arranged to be bounded below by considering only those $k$ and $\ell$ that have large enough gaps.

Comment: such brightness